# Search only the first column of a text file

Tags: php

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
---> 12455  ---> 125  ---> KKK
---> 11366  ---> 120  ---> LLL
---> 12477  ---> 120  ---> YYY
```

I am using the following PHP code to search the file for "---> 124" and I get the following results:

```
---> 12455  ---> 125  ---> KKK
---> 12477  ---> 120  ---> YYY
```

but I want the results to be like this:

```
---> 12455  
---> 12477
```

I want it to return only the first column.

```
<?php
    $file = 'mytext.txt';
    $searchfor = '---> ' . "124";

    // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    // escape special characters in the query
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

    // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
        echo implode($matches[0]);
    } else {
        echo "No matches found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just do an `explode('--->', $yourLine)` and take the `[1]` element of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your approach a little bit. Instead of storing the search term and separator in a single string, use two variables.

```
$sep = '--->';
$searchfor = '124';

$pattern = "/^$sep\s+($searchfor\d+)\s+.*/m";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo implode(' ', $matches[1])."\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
12455 12477
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/75549)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, seperate your concerns:

1. Read the file
2. Parse the content
3. Search

Using Iterators, you can achieve something great here but it will need a deeper understanding of OOP and the iterator interface. What i'll recommend is a simpler approach:

```
<?php
//Read the file line by line
$handle = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while(!foef($handle)){
    $content = fgets($handle);

    //Parse the line
    $content = explode('---> ', $content);

    //Analyse the line
    if($content[1] == 124){
        echo $content[0]."\n";
    }

}
fclose($handle);
```

That should be it, just adapt it as you see it, i haven't tested the code here!

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is always as you have shown, then:

1. Read the file line by line;
2. `explode();` each line by space  ;
3. Read the element `[1]` of the result;

This seems to be most logical to me. No need for `regex` in here, because it will work slower then simple `explode` operation.

Here is an example:

```
$handle = fopen( 'file.txt', 'r' );
if ( $handle ) {
    while ( ( $line = fgets( $handle ) ) !== false ) {
        $matches = explode( ' ', $line );
        if ( $matches[4] == '124' )
            echo $matches[1] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2475714 How is that a problem? Should work just fine.
Using this method you would explode by \r\n and then iterate through the array and explode the line by ' ' and then element [1] of the result will be the first column.

Comment: @user2475714 I checked it on 120000 entries, the script run 5 seconds on my old dual core witch windows xp ... I don't see the problem.

Comment: @user2475714: It wouldn't be slow. I just benchmarked all the solutions posted here (with a file containing `12000` lines of text). This one took `0.1953649520874` seconds, Mathieu Dumoulin's version took `0.14685893058777` seconds and my regex solution took `0.10286807060242` seconds.

Comment: @AmalMurali With 12k lines mine takes 0.03 seconds.

Comment: @AmalMurali
$time = microtime(true); /*code*/ echo microtime(true)-$time . 'sec';

Though I will note that yours was a little faster, probably just my specs.

Answer (score 1):

change `"/^.*$pattern.*\$/m"` to `"/$pattern\d*/i"`

and then `echo implode($matches[0]);` to `foreach($matches[0] as $item) echo "$item<br />\r\n";`

Comment: your code works fine... but i get `---> 12455 ---> 12477` and i want `---> 12455
---> 12477` i mean both of them should be displayed one below the other not in a single line...

Comment: @user2475714 Those are exactly the same. See my answer above for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
--->\s\d{5}
```

regex is overkill here, a simple `explode('--->', $str)` and selecting the first element would suffice

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$lines = explode('---> ', $file);
for($i=1; $i<count($lines); $i=$i+3)
if(strpos($lines[$i], '124')!==false)
    $col[$i/3] = /*'--> ' . */$lines[$i];
print_r($col);
```

That seems to work just fine. Uncomment the comment above if you want the --> included in the output. Also, the resulting $col array is indexed with the row number it is found. Just replace [$i/3] with [] if you don't want that.

Furthering this:

```
function SearchFileByColumn($contents, $col_num, $search, $col_count = 3) {
    $segs = explode('---> ', $contents);
    for($i=$col_num; $i<count($segs); $i=$i+$col_count)
        if(strpos($segs[$i], $search) !== false)
            $res[] = $segs[$i];
    return $res;
}

$results = SearchFileByColumn($contents, 1, '124');
```